# Skobbler iOS download package error "Invalid property type for propertyName"

Tags: ios, skmaps

So I'm trying to test download a package "catalonia" for offline use as follows:

```
- (void) syncSkobblerMapsForTrip:(Trip *)trip withProgressView:(UIProgressView *) progressView{    
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    SKTPackage *cataloniaPackage = [appDelegate.skMapsObject packageForCode:@"ESREG10"];


    SKTDownloadObjectHelper *region = [SKTDownloadObjectHelper downloadObjectHelperWithSKTPackage:cataloniaPackage];

    [[SKTDownloadManager sharedInstance] requestDownloads:@[region] startAutomatically:YES withDelegate:self withDataSource:self];
}
```

And I'm getting the following error in the console:

2015-01-27 17:26:42.621 Tripcipe[48381:1070885] Invalid property type for propertyName downloadType. Skip

2015-01-27 17:26:42.622 Tripcipe[48381:1070885] Invalid property type for propertyName bSkmDownloaded. Skip

2015-01-27 17:26:42.622 Tripcipe[48381:1070885] Invalid property type for propertyName bNBDownloaded. Skip

2015-01-27 17:26:42.622 Tripcipe[48381:1070885] Invalid property type for propertyName bTexturesDownloaded. Skip

2015-01-27 17:26:42.622 Tripcipe[48381:1070885] Invalid property type for propertyName bNBUnzipped. Skip

When I try to download the same package in the framework demo it seems to work fine though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We're looking into what might be the issue

Comment: Actually we realized the package download still works regardless of the logs so it's not as important.

Comment: If the log message still persists, please send us a demo project so that we can investigate (we could not reproduce it in the official demo project)